# Cannot disable autorotate lock in theos tweak

Tags: objective-c, tweak, theos

here's the code

```
[[%c(SBOrientationLockManager) sharedInstance] unlock];
```

This compiles in Theos fine but does nothing.
The Methods exist in the header file.
Has this changed in iOS 7?

Whatever I try will not turn off the rotation lock and as I am not hooking an app, i cannot use:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be different in iOS 7 as I just tried it and it worked for me. I suppose you are hooking in SpringBoard right ? Otherwise it wouldn't work, because `SBOrientationLockManager` is part of SpringBoard

Comment: I'm hooking another class from another framework actually and want to unlock temporarily. I have springboard in as a filter.

Comment: Maybe the `SBOrientationLockManager` class is not loaded in that framework ? You can get a list of the loaded classes at runtime using `objc_getClassList` if you're not sure. (Also, the filter is restrictive, it means the .dylib will be loaded only for the given bundle ID)